# Need help in accessing .so libs in MeteorJS - I have tried node-gyp to get cpp instead but didn't work. Hence I have to resort to accessing .so libs

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, shared-libraries, node.js-addon

I had compatability issues with node-gyp and nodejs versions hence dropped that idea. But there must be a way to import these .so files in meteorjs. I am looking for something similar to dyn.load in R.

Any help is much appreciated..Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide the errors you are currrently encountering or some code?

Comment: Hey Mitchken! can you suggest anything on accessing .so libs in meteorjs